# Capacitor Selection For Induction Heater

Tags: capacitor

I am looking to select capacitors for an induction value. The target value of the bank is 4.7uF, and my power input is going to be 48V up to 10A. Based on some simple calculations, I estimate the frequency will be around 50kHz.

At the moment, my plan is to put 10 of [these .47uf caps](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/871-B32672L4474J000) in parallel, which are reated for 450vdc 200vac. From what I've read, the requirements seem to be just to have capacitors that are rated for 3x the input voltage and are metallized polypropylene film capacitors.

I did some digging into the datasheet, and the dV/dt value seems to be plenty. If the frequency is in the neighborhood of 50khz, then the period would be 20 microseconds, which means the from zero to max voltage would be 5 microseconds, so I could theoretically have a voltage of 1000v given this dv/dt value, so 48v shouldn't be a concern.

[image]

The part that I'm concerned about is this allowable voltage vs frequency graph.
[image]

It seems the allowable AC voltage drops to around 25V at 50Khz. Is this a cause for concern? On examples I have seen online, they all use caps that also have a less than 50 volt rating at 50khz.

Comment: dV/dt is peak, for short periods, not continuously.  The voltage or current (RMS) ratings are what you're looking for.